# Word for a strong election win that grants a candidate a referendum

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm in search of the word that describes the strong referendum that a candidate receives upon a strong election win that grants him or her vast leeway in enacting policy reform. I can't quite get it; referendum is close, but I believe that there's a more specific word for this, perhaps 3-4 syllables and starting with a 'c'.

Comment: General Reference. Any competent native speaker would expect the word *mandate* at the end of the question, and see the glaring misuse of *referendum* as indicating poor knowledge of English political terminology.

Comment: Sometimes even teenagers (I have no idea how old Matt B. is or whether he's a native speaker of English) have "senior moments" where they forget such obvious and common terms. It used to happen to me all the time. Still does. :-(

Comment: But if the asker doesn't know or doesn't remember the word "mandate", how is he supposed to look it up in a general reference? If he knew the word but had questions about the definition, he could look it up in a dictionary, but the reverse process is much tougher.

Answer (score 5):

I don’t know what you mean there by *referendum* — that isn’t how I use that word — but you might be looking for the rather overused ***mandate***.

Answer (score 3):

If a candidate wins in a ***[landslide](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/landslide)*** (by a large margin "a : a great majority of votes for one side; b : an overwhelming victory"), then he or she has what is called a ***[mandate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mandate?show=0&t=1350444404)*** ("an authorization to act: *He won the election so convincingly that he believed he had been given a mandate for change.*)